# SSH refusing connections for a couple minutes after boot

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, home-server

I have a home server I use hobby projects and I frequently use SSH on the machine, however after it (re)boots, any SSH connection attempt is refused for around a couple minutes before I can login normally. Pinging the machine reveals nothing out of the ordinary, as it responds to pings within 45 seconds of starting up, any before that will timeout, presumably as it's still booting or is yet to connect to WiFi.

I know it's not DNS related since I only use the IP to login anyway, and it's not firewall related since I've tried it with the firewall disabled and I get the same result. My openSSH version is OpenSSH_8.9p1 and my OS is Ubuntu Server 22.04.2.

Is it just because that's the fastest openSSH takes to start up naturally, or is there a particular reason it seems slow to allow connections?

Edit: I ran systemd-analyze blame and I saw systemd-networkd-wait-online.service at the top that took 2min 13ms to load, longer than anything else. Running systemd-analyze critical-chain returns:

```
graphical.target @2min 17.917s
└─multi-user.target @2min 17.917s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @2min 16.718s +310ms
    └─snapd.service @2min 3.473s +13.242s
      └─basic.target @2min 3.450s
        └─sockets.target @2min 3.450s
          └─snapd.socket @2min 3.449s +928us
            └─sysinit.target @2min 3.420s
              └─cloud-init.service @2min 2.910s +509ms
                └─cloud-init-local.service @1.946s +820ms
                  └─systemd-remount-fs.service @507ms +20ms
                    └─systemd-journald.socket @474ms
                      └─system.slice @453ms
                        └─-.slice @453ms
```

Comment: This is not because of how long OpenSSH takes to start up - that is very fast.  Likewise its nothing to do with WIFI as you would not be able to ping it if that were the issue. The issue will relate to SystemD and prerequisites which need to load or time-out before SSH loads but after networking comes up. Try running systemd-analyze blame which may or may not help find the problem.

Comment: Also systemd-analyze critical-chain

Comment: I ran systemd-analyze blame and I saw systemd-networkd-wait-online.service at the top that took 2min 13ms to load, longer than anything else. I added the output of systemd-analyze critical-chain to the original question since it wouldn't fit in a comment.

Comment: Formal note for future reference: relevant information should be in the question body, not in a comment, regardless if it's short enough for a comment or not.